# Which software to use for drawing nice architecture/deployment diagrams?

Tags: architecture, diagram

I see a lot of nice diagrams showing the infrastructure of various sites, deployment options, high level designs etc. I am wondering which software ppl normally use to draw these types of diagrams. Please let me know which is your preferred software for drawing these diagrams. Something like,

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_swahP4sgx0k/S4v_wE8cr5I/AAAAAAAAACk/CmV9zw4O8O4/s1600-h/RedditArchDiagramWhiteBG.png

Comment: The diagram you posted appears to have been drawn in MS PowerPoint. I'm pretty sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use ConceptDraw Pro. It's an MS Visio like software, part of [ConceptDraw Office suite](http://www.conceptdraw.com/products.php) which include a Mind Mapper and an MS Project like.

It's not free but run on Windows, Linux and OS-X.

Answer (score 1):

**UML deployment diagrams** are, in my opinion, your best choice. There are too many tools that you can use - altova umodel, visual paradigm, star uml, boUML, eclipse and netbeans pluging, etc. My favorite tool for deployment diagram is [Altova UModel](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools to draw diagrams and I have used lot of them, however, I prefer Visio 2010 among them. [Visio](http://visiotoolbox.com) is a Microsoft product which has great features and easy to use. If asked personally I will say it is one of the best diagramming software available in the market.